# Command line equivalent of TFS Merge?

Tags: asp.net, command-line, tfs, source-control-explorer

What would be the command line equivalent of a TFS* Merge action from within Visual Studio 2013?  There seem to be various switches for the `tf merge` command so I'd like to know what the entire command would look like for the default behavior within Visual Studio 2013.

*TFS 2012

I'm expecting the result after running the command to be check-outs in TFS with merges to address within Visual Studio 2013.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll find that the very basic

```
tf merge folder1 folder2 /recursive
```

is what you're after.

Also, if you add `preview` to the command you'll be able to experiment with the various options until you get the result you're after. It's a great way to see how the merge works without worrying about damaging anything.